# Where to add theme name, creator and theme version in Shopify Theme?

Tags: shopify

In the basic theme of Shopify, when you hit customize and theme settings we see the following information at the very bottom of the customization tab:

DEBUT (VERSION 11.1.3) 
Design and support by Shopify

My question is, when I start developing my theme where should I add this information so it can appear there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These settings are specified in the **settings_schema.json**. For more information about Settings Schema, have a look at [Shopify documentation](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/theme-editor/settings-schema). Sample JSON from a Shopify theme

```
 {
    "name": "theme_info",
    "theme_name": "Debut",
    "theme_author": "Shopify",
    "theme_version": "1.0.0",
    "theme_documentation_url": "http:\/\/shopify.com\/",
    "theme_support_email": "shopify-support@email.com"
  }
```